# Not able to use wireguard after Handshake

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, cmd.exe, wireguard

I am trying to run wireguard using the commands                                        `wireguard.exe /installtunnelservice "C:\wireguard\we.conf"`     for starting the tunnel and `wireguard.exe /uninstalltunnelservice we`  for uninstalling it using the Command Prompt in Windows with Administrator Mode.

So, what is going wrong, that I cannot retrieve anything from the server.

[image]

```
                                       Edit
```

The configuration file I am using is as follows:
***Important Point :*** the handshake is complete.

we.conf

[Interface]

PrivateKey = 4DPul16PKN5HwDlVo0rmbLBWk0svJz9WTq4Bsww6O1Q=

ListenPort = 51822

Address = 10.10.0.120/24

[Peer]

PublicKey = uf1AVfFOVfcsN5aY34RX2vDwujQ1j58/oDM8h00pgVA=

AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

Endpoint = 72.88.206.178:51822

PersistentKeepalive = 25

Comment: You should provide us your configuration file as an edit to your question.  The uninstall command seems incomplete.

Comment: Hey, I have added the configuration file, as an edit in the original question. Also, the uninstall comment seems to turn off the VPN Connection. I navigate to the directory where, wireguard.exe is already present and then run it so, that could be probebly why it seems incomplete. Please let me know further details. Thank you !